# EXTJS Grid Panel Listener - Retrieving Data from an Object

Tags: extjs, extjs4, gridpanel

Guys, I'm quite new to extJS and I would like your help.
I have this Grid.Panel with listeners, I don't know if i got it right. Anyway, I got it to print out its properties but I cant get the data. Here is what the console printed out.

```
Object { internalId=, raw={...}, data={...}, more...}

after clicking it:
```

[image: see encircled in red]

The "data" encircled in red. How do get those information? I believe inside "data" are the information to when I clicked the certain row.

Comment: are you binding this information to grid? or you want to access it and explicitly load it on the grid?

Comment: It is hard to say what exactly your problem is... Do want to access fields of a record? Do you want to load records into a grid and show specific fields?

Comment: I already loaded the data into the grid.Panel and with a listener I want to access the records in order to do another action.

Comment: The best answer here will depend on your next action, if for example you want to update a single record in a database, the approach would be very different than if you wanted to export the entire dataset to file for example. What is your goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a load listener on the grid store as suggested by @sra and iterate over records to perform another operation.

```
gridStore().load({
    callback : function(records, operation, success) {
                 //Iterate over each record and get data from record
                 var name = records[0].get('name');
    }});
```